# VBA to select value from dropdown that does not have an "id"

Tags: vba, web-scraping

I've used VBA to open the following IE page: https://insurance.qbe.com.au/portal/caravan/form/estimate

I now want my code to select the first option of the first dropdown - which is caravan type.

Here is the HTML of the dropdown list:

[image]

I've tried the following code to select "Caravan" from the dropdown:

```
IE.Document.GetElementsbyClassName("ui-select-search ui-select-toggle ng-pristine ng-valid ng-touched")(1).Click
```

Also tried

```
IE.Document.GetElementsbyClassName("ui-select-search ui-select-toggle ng-pristine ng-valid ng-touched")(1).SelectedIndex = 1
```

Also tried the seemingly strange, like

```
IE.Document.GetElementsbyClassName("ui-select-search ui-select-toggle ng-pristine ng-valid ng-touched")(1).Value = "Caravan"
```

So I guess what I really want to know is: How do you select a value from a dropdown list when its associated HTML only seems to have a class (and no id)?

I then expanded the HTML to see if I was missing something. I see the following towards the end of the HTML associated with the dropdown and I think the solution relies on this (but really not sure at all, at this point).

[image]

So I'm no longer sure which HTML will affect the value that needs to be selected for the dropdown - and also not sure about how to actually select that value

Answer (score 0):

GetElementsbyClassName doesn't work on all versions of IE. 
Do this:

- Get a collection of all the selects: lists
- Iterate the lists collection : l
- Set list l's selectedIndex to the first item: selectedIndex = 0

**Done!!**

```
Dim lists, l 'Removed the opts and o variables you dim'd here as they don't feature in the code
Set lists = IE.document.getElementsByTagName("select") 'edited this line to include IE. before document 
For Each l in lists
    If instr(1, l.className,"ui-select-search", 1) then
         l.selectedIndex = 0        
    End If
next
```

Comment: Makes sense - you're getting a tag called 'select', then going through each element within the tag so that, if its classname contains "ui-select-search", you'll simply select the first of its associated indexes. However, for whatever reason, this is not working. I've also edited your "set lists = " line to include the IE. I'll post my updated code in a new post

Comment: Nice catch, I didn't think to qualify my document reference.

Comment: I'm a little out of my depth at the moment but it feels like the l.selectedIndex is an incomplete reference? I think the code doesn't necessarily know what l is. I've tried `IE.document.getElementsByTagName("select")(0).SelectedIndex = 1` in place of that line, but that's not working either :/